# How to change where Spack stores the spack-stage directory?

Tags: linux, package-managers, spack

Spack by default writes (on my system) into a directory `spack-stage` inside `/tmp/`. This directory can get full when building something big (e.g. GCC itself), at least in the shared system I am using:

```
fatal error: error writing to /tmp/ccPlIYSg.s: No space left on device
```

Is there any way to tell Spack to use a different location for `spack-stage`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to the [spack documentation](https://spack.readthedocs.io/en/latest/config_yaml.html#basic-settings) you just need to specify `$TMP` to point to a directory of your choice.

> Builds can be faster in temporary directories on some (e.g., HPC) systems.
>      Specifying `$tempdir` will ensure use of the default temporary directory
>      (i.e., `$TMP` or `$TMPDIR`).
>      Another option that prevents conflicts and potential permission issues is
>      to specify `~/.spack/stage`, which ensures each user builds in their home
>      directory.